# Error calling a qt executable in Matlab

Tags: qt, matlab

I have a Matlab file when I get a qt compiled executable to run using the unix(), but I'm getting an error.

the code:

```
unix('/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui');
```

the error:

```
/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui: symbol lookup error: /home/matt/Desktop
/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData7detach3Ev
```

Comment: It seems to be an error from Unix. 

You may refer below link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469364

Comment: executing a vtk executable it works, `unix('/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolume/planevolume');`

Comment: Actually the above link is some library file for qt4 as mention in the thread 
"removing
/usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00f97000)
/usr/local/lib/beidqt/libQtCore.so.4 
resolved my issue."

So i think, it will help you in resolving your problem.

Also if you follow this link, you may find ample of solutions:https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=_ZN9QListData7detach3Ev&oq=_ZN9QListData7detach3Ev&gs_l=hp.3..0.8589.8589.0.9645.1.1.0.0.0.0.91.91.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1j2.kn39TrGkfdY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=24e3607ac87a03e2&biw=1517&bih=727

Comment: @skg I don't have those files already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamically linked libraries are linked when the application is started, the error is saying that the OS cannot find the library that contains the stuff for `QList`, that library is `QtCore`.

Make sure Qt's runtime libraries are somewhere where the OS can find them - usually `/usr/lib(64)`.  My guess is that you do not have the runtimes but are using Qt's SDK, so QtCreator uses those for compiling - but they are not on your OS's path for when it is ran outside of that.

Comment: I have `Qtcore` in `/usr/lib64`, it is `libQtCore.so.4.6.2`

Comment: What is the Qt version you are compiling against?

Comment: No, I meant _exactly_ what version are you using in the SDK.  It should tell you in QtCreator in the project's build settings.  If you copy and paste the `unix(..)` call arg into a terminal, does your program run, or does give the same error?

Comment: In a terminal it works. It's only in Matlab That i get the error.

Comment: Well that's unexpected.  I read here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html that Unix/Linux Matlab launches itself from a Bourne shell, whereas most Linux distros use a Bash shell, I'm wondering if there's some essential environment setting not being done in the `matlab` launch script.  You'll have to check that out.